# Static iOS framework with bitcode enabled for iOS9

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7

I have a static framework and would like to add a bitcode support for it (iOS9 invention). At the moment when I set bitcode to YES I get this:

```
-bundle and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together
```

So the question is, how do I enable bitcode for a static library to avoid this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I avoided this problem by the following build settings.

- Set '**Enable Bitcode**' '**No**'
- Add '**-fembed-bitcode**' to '**Other C Flags**'

Comment: hm ... could you please explain what you have done there? I don't want to loose the bitcode as more and more apps will require it in the future ...

Comment: Also, did you set it in the app app or in the framework (static lib)?

Comment: Unfortunately the static library doesn't build with this setting at all. The error message is exactly the same like with the bitcode enabled as it should be ... :(

Comment: I'm sorry. I had misunderstood your question.
I had avoided `-fembed-bitcode` and `-fembed-bitcode-marker`.